# Show link_to in yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing a problem with `link_to` and `yield`. I was successfull in showing the root page (start page) in the `yield`-area of `application.erb.html` all other links like "help" (see below) are shown on a seperate page.

that is what my *application.erb.html* looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="main-inner">


        <div id="content">
                <%= yield %>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

In *navbar.html.erb* I definied two links:

```
<%= link_to "Start", root_path %>
```

which works perfect. the second one

```
<%= link_to "Help", help_path %>
```

works but is not shown in the `yield`-area.

*routes.rb* looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'set_language/english'
  get 'set_language/german'
  #scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de/ do
  #  root :to => 'pages#home'
  #  get "pages/home"
  #end
  get 'pages/home'
  get 'pages/help'
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/new'
  resources :sessions,      :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root :to => "pages#home"

  #root                'pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  post   'signup'  => 'users#create'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  #delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
```

I tried using `content-for` and giving the `yield` a name identifier but unfortunately without any success.

Comment: Is there no link at all or link exists but with empty (invisible) content? Have you try to do same without `t()` function?

Comment: @oklas is right.  try changing `<%= link_to t("help"), help_path %>` into `<%= link_to "Help", help_path %>` and see if the link now appears. If it does, your locale isn't set up correctly.

Comment: Did you use i18n gem? remove t and use `<%= link_to "Help", help_path %>`

Comment: I think this a missunderstanding. the link appears correctly either with t(...) or without but the content behind it appears not in the yield area